# How to find the adjoint operator

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

Let $f \in \mathcal{D}(
${$(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2| x>0,y>0)$} and define

$T(\phi(x)):=\int_0^x f(x,y) \phi(y)dy$ for every $\phi \in \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R})$

Find the adjoint operator $T^*$.

The adjoint operator is defined as:
Let $f,g$ be in $\mathcal{D(\mathbb{R})}$
the adjoint operator in relation to T, if existent satisfies the following equation
$\langle T(f),g \rangle =\langle f,T^*(g) \rangle$

Let $f \in \mathcal{D}(
${$(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2| x>0,y>0)$}
further let $\phi,\psi$ be in $\mathcal{D(\mathbb{R})}$

$\langle T(\phi),\psi \rangle =\int_{\Omega} (\int_0^x f(x,y) \phi(y)dy) \psi(x)dx$ where $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}$

My calculations:

I would like to use Integration by parts for y:
$\int_0^x f(x,y)\phi(y)dy=[F \phi]_0^x-\int_0^x F \phi' dy$

I am a little bit confused how to evaluate $[F \phi]_0^x$ , what I did was:
$[F \phi]_0^x=F(x,y)\phi(x)-F(0,y)\phi(0)=F(x,y)\phi(x)$

Hope this was correct.

As a result of the integration by parts I get:
$\int_0^x f(x,y)\phi(y)dy=F(x,y)\phi(x)-\int_0^x F(x,y) \phi'(y) dy$

$\int_{\Omega} (\int_0^x f(x,y) \phi(y)dy) \psi(x)dx=\int_{\Omega}(F(x,y)\phi(x)-\int_0^x F(x,y) \phi'(y) dy)\psi(x)dx=\int_{\Omega}(F(x,y)\phi(x)\psi(x)-\psi(x) \int_0^x F(x,y) \phi'(y) dy)dx$

It looks like I would need "to get the $\psi$ in to the integral" so that I can continue my calculation. At this point I am stuck.

I would be thankful for a hint.

Comment: Instead of integration by parts, consider changing the order of integration

Comment: What exactly does $\mathcal D(\Omega)$ mean in this context?

Comment: @BenGrossmann $\mathcal{D}(\Omega):=C_c^\infty(\Omega)$

Comment: Perfect, thank you

Comment: @BenGrossmann What do you mean with "changing the order of integration"? Do you mean to first integrate over $\Omega$

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I mean

Comment: @BenGrossmann After some calculations I get $\int_{\Omega} \underbrace{(\int_0^x f(x,y)\phi(y)dy)}_{=:g(x,y)} \psi(x)dx=\int_{\Omega} g(x,y) \psi(x)dx=-\int_{\Omega} (\int_0^x \psi(y)dy) \frac{d}{dx}g(x,y)dx=-\int_{\Omega} (\int_0^x \psi(y)dy) f(x,x)\phi(x)dx=-\int_{\Omega} (\int_0^x \psi(y) f(x,x) dy) \phi(x)dx$

Comment: My Problem is that  I would need a expression that looks like -$\int_{\Omega} (\int_0^x \psi(y) f(x,y) dy) \phi(x)dx$, but by deriviating g(x,y) I get a "double x" in $f$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my calculation:
$$
\langle T\phi, \psi \rangle
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} T\phi(x) \, \psi(x) \, dx
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left( \int_{0}^{x} f(x,y)\,\phi(y) \, dy \right) \, \psi(x) \, dx
\\
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \phi(y) \, \left( \int_{y}^{\infty} f(x,y)\,\psi(x) \, dx \right) \, dy
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \phi(y) \, T^*\psi(y) \, dy
= \langle \phi, T^*\psi \rangle,
$$
where
$$
T^*\psi(y) = \int_{y}^{\infty} f(x,y)\,\psi(x) \, dx.
$$

Have I missed anything caused by the support of $f$ in the first quadrant? I cannot see how that makes a difference. The outer integrals over all of the reals reduce to being over just the positive reals, but as far as I see they can still be written as integrals over all of the reals.

Comment: What did you do in this step: $$
 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left( \int_{0}^{x} f(x,y)\,\phi(y) \, dy \right) \, \psi(x) \, dx
\\
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \phi(y) \, \left( \int_{y}^{\infty} f(x,y)\,\psi(x) \, dx \right) \, dy
$$ I don't understand how you where able to "move" $\psi$ into the integral and $\phi$ "out" of it

Comment: That's just swapping the order of integration, from $y$ innermost and $x$ outermost to $x$ innermost and $y$ outermost.

Comment: Oh I totally missed that. Thank you!

Comment: I tried to comprehend your calculation but, when I change the order of integration, I get $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (\int_{0}^x f(x,y) \phi(y) dy) \psi(x) dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (\int_{y}^{\infty} \psi(x) dx)   f(x,y) \phi(y)dy$

I can't pull $f(x,y)$ into the inner integral because it depends on $x$.

Comment: Because of this I get $T^*(\psi)(x)=(\int_y^{\infty} \psi(x) dx) f(x,y)$

Comment: @John.W. It seems like you have to repeat how iterated integrals work. The function must stay inside the integral when it depends on the variable of integration.